# What are the characteristics of a raster to Netcdf layer in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, raster, attribute-table, netcdf

Specifically, when trying to edit the attribute table? This is would be for work purely in ArcMap, and converting raster to Netcdf. I have a land cover layer (that I've converted to a raster to convert to netcdf) that has an column from its attribute table that I need in the Netcdf attribute table. I have tried joining the land cover layer with the raster and then converting it to netcdf, but the attribute table for the netcdf only has OID, VALUE, and COUNT.